# create array of object with new line ( newline Json standard format conversion for BigQuery)

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I've created a json object to store it in Cloud Storage but I need it to be converted as newline Json standard format so BigQuery can read it.

This is my code:

```
  items = []
  for item in item_list:
    item = {'key': item}
    items.append(item)
```

The actual current output looks like this:

```
[{'item': 'stuff'}, {'item': 'stuff'}, {'item': 'stuff'}, {'item': 'stuff'}]
```

And I need it to be like this:

```
{'item': 'stuff'}
{'item': 'stuff'}
{'item': 'stuff'}
{'item': 'stuff'}
```

From what I understand I need to add new line `'\n'` between each object on my array. How can I do this?

I'm using the `upload_from_string()` method to upload the object to Cloud Storage.

Comment: This is not true, JSON newline format must be 1 single json object per line. So either 1). you have object containing array of more objects on single line, or 2). each item is on its own line. No start/end of array and no commas.

Comment: you are probably right. please feel free to provide and answer and I will update my question

Comment: I have added an answer now, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery requires JSON-NL format (aka NDJSON) which is a single JSON object on each file line.

Basically it means if you take any random line of the file, then you must be able to deserialize the JSON without needing any other parts.

So to make the file, rather than serialize the array, you instead serialize each object independently.

```py
item_list = [ ...<all items>... ]

with open('send-to-bigquery.ndjson', 'w') as out:
    for item in item_list:
        out.write(json.dumps(item))
        out.write('\n')
```

To create as a string:

```py
lines = [json.dumps(item) for item in item_list]
file_content = '\n'.join(lines)
upload_from_string(file_content)  # to GCS
```

Comment: How would you translate with without writing or opening any file. I've added a comment in my question. I'm using the `upload_from_string()` to upload the data to cloud storage so I need a solution that work with this.

Comment: Added new code block at bottom with example

Answer (score 1):

So first we cast the list to a String. Then we replace the "[" with a "[\n", so it has a newline after the square brackets. Then we replace "]" with a "\n]" for the same reason. Lastly we replace all the "}, " with "}, \n"

```
jsonString = str([{'item': 'stuff'}, {'item': 'stuff'}, {'item': 'stuff'}, {'item': 'stuff'}])

jsonString = jsonString.replace("[", "[\n")
jsonString = jsonString.replace("]", "\n]")
jsonString = jsonString.replace("}, ", "},\n")
print(jsonString)
```

Comment: I've updated my desired output on my question based on Hitobat comment and It's working.